Nextjs Loading Worker was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”)
I have some files inside the path: public/resources that are in .js format. Locally, they are loaded, and I can execute everything as needed. However, when deploying to production, and the application tries to access these files (a third-party SDK), I encounter the following error: Loading Worker from .... was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).
How can I resolve this in Next.js?
